# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: NoSuchSessionError: Tried to run command without establishing a connection

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver

I was trying to use `selenium-webdriver` with `nodeJs`. Every thing was going smooth but as soon as it end  it pop up with this error in terminal.What's wrong in this.

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: NoSuchSessionError: Tried to run
> command without establishing a connection.

Here is my code,

```
let webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
const { Builder, Key, until } = require('selenium-webdriver');

By = webdriver.By;

let driver = new webdriver.Builder().forBrowser('firefox').build();

driver.get('https://www.google.com/');

pause(2, ScraperExample);

function ScraperExample() {
  console.log('Scrapping the Pagee...');

  pause(3, QuitDriver);
}

function pause(Time, FuncName) {
  setTimeout(FuncName, Time * 1000);
}

function QuitDriver() {
  driver.close();
  driver.quit();
  console.log('The Driver is set to off...');
}
```

Comment: It's writing in the err message "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning". Some method(s) should return a Promise, so you need to find which one and handle it with a try-catch "try{ //code } catch(err){ // handle the err }"

Answer (score 0):

I found one of the solution for my own question, we can resolve it by using any one of this `drive.close()` or  `driver.quit()` if both of going to be used than we will face issues.

````
function QuitDriver() {
  driver.quit();
  console.log('The Driver is set to off...');
}```
````